# Copy local Git branch with same upstream

Tags: git, version-control

My Git workflow means that I usually - but not always - work in master and mostly make use of interactive rebase. Sometimes I make some commits on master and realise (before pushing) that I want to split some of them off into a feature branch.

If I do this:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

then I have a new branch in which to re-arrange/delete commits but it is tracking local `master` rather than origin/master. Git prompt and `git status` show that I'm not ahead and interactive rebase has nothing to work with (`noop`). So I manually run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

before starting to work. This is annoying. I've also lost the relevant @{upstream} at this point, so I don't even have an alias for it.

When I see similar questions asked, the answer I always find is to run:

```
git checkout -b feature -t origin/master
```

However, this means the `feature` branch does not contain my local commits on master.

If I try to supply the `<start_point>` parameter to `git checkout` Git says `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'feature' at the same time.`. I don't think this is actually what I want anyway (the start point should be the same).

Is it possible to combine creating a new branch from a local branch, setting the upstream to the local branch's upstream and checking it out in one step?

Comment: May I ask why you want/need to set the upstream of your feature branch?  Typically, after rebasing `feature` on `master`, you would push, creating a new branch on the remote in the process.

Comment: As above: I want to work on the commits that are ahead of upstream in a convenient way, separating them from any parallel unfinished work. That means seeing the correct prompt, interactive rebase showing those commits by default, `git diff @{upstream}..` showing what I'd push. In some cases I may want to pull rebase changes from upstream that already made it in, or push this branch to a remote feature branch for sharing before integrating with master.

Comment: This sounds like a peculiar workflow to me.  Typically, you would create a `feature` branch from `master`, do some work, then when you want to bring it into `master`, you would rebase on `master` and let it fast-forward the `master` branch.

Comment: The point is that I did not create the `feature` branch up-front. I mostly work on one thing at a time, or multiple items that a small enough not to require feature branches. I've found planning and creating branches up-front is less efficient. In the case that I need to split off some changes - perhaps because one has grown in scope or needs separate testing - I only need two commands and some interactive rebasing. I'd like to get that down to one command (& rebasing). Rebasing/merging the completed work is not a problem; interactive rebasing is used for dropping and squashing commits.

Comment: I tried 'git checkout -b MyFeatureBranch MyNewBranch -t master' and got the error 'fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'MyFeatureBranch' at the same time.'